# How do I deploy Microsoft 365 Defender Trial -- Endpoints menu is missing

Tags: azure-active-directory, windows-defender, microsoft365-defender

I signed up for a 365 E5 trial so that I could test Microsoft 365 Defender. Once the trial was setup on MSFT's side, I added each of the security roles(Security Administrator etc) to my user via admin.microsoft.com.

I also assigned an E5 license to the user.

This was yesterday.

Then I am attempting to follow [Onboard Windows devices using a local script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/configure-endpoints-script?view=o365-worldwide) from 09/01/2023.

Step 1 says:

```
Open the configuration package .zip file (WindowsDefenderATPOnboardingPackage.zip) that you downloaded from the service onboarding wizard. You can also get the package from Microsoft 365 Defender portal:

In the navigation pane, select Settings > Endpoints > Device management > Onboarding.
```

However, I have no Endpoints menu as best as I can tell:
[image]

Comment: Is this a programming question? [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

In my environment, I assigned the user the **Office 365 license and Security Administrator role** to the user:

[image]

When I singed in **Microsoft 365 Defender portal,** I am able to see the Endpoint menu:

[image]

> **Note** that: Endpoints missing issue usually occurs if the user does not required licenses. Check this  [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender/prerequisites?view=o365-worldwide#licensing-requirements) for license requirement. The user must have either Global Administrator role or with Security Administrator role.

Try assigning the **Office 365 E3/M365 E3 license** to the user and check if it resolves the issue as you might have a E5 license without windows and audio conferencing.

When I tried to login with the user with no proper license assigned, ***Endpoints menu is missing***:

[image]

**As a workaround**, you can also sign-in directly to Onboarding link https://security.microsoft.com/securitysettings/endpoints/onboarding or the Endpoints link https://security.microsoft.com/securitysettings/endpoints

[image]

**References:**

[Endpoint menu missing in security.microsoft.com - Microsoft Community Hub](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-defender-for-endpoint/endpoint-menu-missing-in-security-microsoft-com/m-p/3021187) by Jack_Chen1780

[how to enable MDE in security.microsoft.com - missing menu - Microsoft Community Hub](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-defender-for-endpoint/how-to-enable-mde-in-security-microsoft-com-missing-menu/m-p/3270735) by Felix Brand

Answer (score 0):

@stubble jumper

What you are facing is absolutely a license issue (assuming the permissions are correctly assigned). I have encountered this before and the solution was to assign a correct license.
I recommend: D*efender for Endpoint Plan 1* or *Plan 2*.

Here is a link to further guide on Licensing requirements https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/minimum-requirements?view=o365-worldwide#licensing-requirements